# HTML Canvas - color transition between shapes ( shapes not overlapping)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

The image is what I am looking forward to achieve using html canvas, **without using blur or shadow**.

[image]

**Question :**
Is there way to achieve right section of the image from left section of the image?

The fiddle for the problem is (basic drawing) [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vyz07113/2d804uwz/15/)

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
d = canvas.width = canvas.height = 400,
sq_size = d / 10,
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas); 

var color=["rgb(10,110,10)", "rgb(81,169,255)","rgb(81,239,255)", 
"rgb(81,255,202)", 
"rgb(81,255,132)","rgb(99,255,81)","rgb(169,255,81)", 
"rgb(239,255,81)", "rgb(255,202,81)","rgb(255,132,81)"];

var x=0, len=color.length;
for(var i=0; i < d; i++){
  while(x < d) {
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = color[c];
    ctx.fillRect(x,i,sq_size,sq_size);
    x = x + sq_size;
  }
  x = 0;
  i = i+sq_size;
}
```

Comment: You have changed the question *"Should work with dataset in millions."* Millions of what? Rather than changing the question after accepting an answer, ask a new question.

Comment: @Blindman67 There was an edit on the answer. It was rejected. The solution works. I have unaccepted it because the render time increased dramatically over a larger dataset.

Comment: I rejected the edit because it was incorrect  The answer is O(1) not O(2*n) as your edit claims. Your edit should have been a comment. The answer draws only 2 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works best for me. Complies with my large dataset.
Not O(1) and I cannot possibly think it can be, or even O(n) (Minor banter).

P.s: Code can be optimised further.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vyz07113/tmajs3pL/1/)

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
d = canvas.width = canvas.height = 250,
sq_size = d / 5,
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.setAttribute('id','cav');

var color=["rgb(10,110,10)", "rgb(81,169,255)","rgb(81,239,255)", "rgb(81,255,202)", "rgb(81,255,132)","rgb(99,255,81)","rgb(169,255,81)", "rgb(239,255,81)", "rgb(255,202,81)","rgb(255,132,81)"];

var x=0, len=color.length;
var prevcolorh;
var colorobj = {};
for(var i=0; i < d;){
    colorobj[i] = {};
    while(x < d) {
        var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        colorobj[i][x] = color[c];
    
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(x, 0, x+sq_size, 0);
    
        var a = (prevcolorh !== undefined) ? prevcolorh : colorobj[i][x];
    
        gradient.addColorStop(0, a);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, colorobj[i][x]);
    
        prevcolorh = colorobj[i][x];
    
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.fillRect(x, i, d, d);
    
        x = x + sq_size;
    }
    x = 0;
    i = i+sq_size;
}

var rgbs = {};
for(var i=0; i<d; i+=sq_size) {
    var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, i+(sq_size/2), d, sq_size);
    rgbs[i] = {};
    var arr = [];

    for (var j = 0, c = 0, n = imgd.data.length; j < n; j += 4, c++) {
        if(j > 0 && j < d*4) {
         arr.push([imgd.data[j],imgd.data[j+1],imgd.data[j+2],imgd.data[+3]]);
        }
    }
    rgbs[i] = arr;
}

for(var k in rgbs) {
    for(var i=0; i<rgbs[k].length; i++) {
        if(rgbs[parseInt(k)+sq_size] !== undefined) {
            var gradient2 = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, parseInt(k)+(sq_size/2), 0, parseInt(k)+(sq_size/2) + sq_size);

            gradient2.addColorStop(0, 'rgba('+rgbs[k][i].join(',')+')');
            gradient2.addColorStop(1, 'rgba('+rgbs[parseInt(k)+sq_size][i].join(',')+')');
        
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient2;
            ctx.fillRect(i, parseInt(k)+(3*sq_size/4), 1, sq_size/2);
         
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get without implementing a blur.

You can use image smoothing [`ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) to blur an image that is very low resolution. Then mix the blurred and unblurred images using [`ctx.globalAlpha`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha)

### Example

`pixelSize` controls the amount of blurring. A value of 1 is the max amount and gets less as this value gets bigger. Must be an integer value eg 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Note results will vary depending on the device and browser / version used.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
const size = canvas.width;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mix = 123; // amount to transition 
const transitionTime = 2; // seconds per transition
const swatches = [0,1,2];
const pixelSize = 2;
// eCurve p = 1 linear curve [default p = 2] is quadratic curve p = 3 cubic curve and so on.
const eCurve = (v, p = 2) =>  v < 0 ? 0 : v > 1 ? 1 : v ** p / (v ** p + (1 - v) ** p);
const cols = [
   [10, 110, 10], [81, 169, 255], [81, 239, 255], [81, 255, 202], [81, 255, 132], 
   [99, 255, 81], [169, 255, 81], [239, 255, 81], [255,202, 81], [255,132,81]
];
const img = document.createElement("canvas");
img.height = img.width = swatches.length * pixelSize;
const imgCtx = img.getContext('2d');
function randomSwatch() {
    swatches.forEach(y => { swatches.forEach(x => {
          imgCtx.fillStyle = "rgb("+cols[Math.random() * cols.length | 0].join(",")+")";
          imgCtx.fillRect(x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize, pixelSize, pixelSize);
     }); });
}
function animationLoop() {
     mix = (mix >= 4 ? (randomSwatch(), 0) : mix) + 1 / (transitionTime * 60);
     ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
     ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, size, size);
     ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
     const a = mix % 2;
     ctx.globalAlpha = eCurve(a > 1 ? 2 - a : a, 3);
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, size, size);
     requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
```